# django_filters filtering by a field not working

Tags: django, django-filters

I am trying to use django_filters to Filter a model based on a field.

these are the models :

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lat=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=6)
    lon=models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=6)
    address_line1=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_line2=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        db_table='providers'


class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    provider=models.ForeignKey(Provider,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        db_table='services'
```

I am using a ModelViewSet

```
class ServiceList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ServiceSerilaizer
    filterset_class=ServiceFilter
```

and here is my Filter class:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class ServiceFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    provider=filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    class Meta:
        model=Service
        fields=["provider_id"]
```

I have defined the URL like this in my urls.py

```
router_service = routers.DefaultRouter()
router_service.register("services", ServiceList, basename='services')



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router_service.urls)),
    path('api/auth/',include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/auth/',include('djoser.urls.authtoken')),
]
```

Now when I hit the URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services/?provider_id=1`

I get all the services, not just the ones for provider_id=1.
Can anyone help? Am I missing something?

Comment: In your `ServiceFilter`, try changing `provider` to `provider_id`

Comment: I did try that, didn't work :(

Comment: Change `provider=filters.NumberFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')` to `provider_id = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="provider_id", lookup_expr='iexact')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply , This didn't work either.

Comment: Do have the filter backend set to  `filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)`

Comment: @Mekicha Thanks for your reply. You are right. I had not added  "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": (
        "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend",
    ), in setting.py file I added it and its working correctly now. So if you add that answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing:

```
DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ( "django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend", ),
```

in your `setting.py` file

Alternatively, you can also set that in your viewset as follows:

```
class ServiceList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset=Service.objects.all()
    serializer_class=ServiceSerilaizer
    filterset_class=ServiceFilter
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```